# Window opens but doesn't responds OpenGL 3.2

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL 2 for my game, and OpenGL 3.2, the window opens up for sure, but doesn't responds. I have no idea what's wrong, I followed a tutorial of ThinMatrix. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have not updated your display in your main game loop using Display.update().
You might also not be syncing your Display with Display.sync(FPS_RATE).

Comment: I did, followed the whole tutorial, its confusing now.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the lwjgl 2 library. It's not the most modern way of using opengl in java. I would suggest using lwjgl 3. In lwjgl 3 only the window is created differently. Otherwise everything is the same.

Comment: oh, would you mind sharing a good OpenGL tutorial with LWJGL 3? Thnx

Comment: you can use https://www.lwjgl.org/guide for window creation. After that just follow thinmatrix's tutorial. As I said only window creation and input is different. Here is a good tutorial about input: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.6.3-Input-handling-with-GLFW